# What does KeysValidator do in django?

Tags: django

I found pice of code where KeysValidator was used, but I didn't undestand what id does, so I've read the documentation https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/contrib/postgres/validators/ and I still don't understand it.

Could someone explain, if we have JSONfield, what is KeysValidator?

Answer (score 1):

It is a validator that is used for a `JSONField` to check if the JSON blob is a dictionary with (at least) the given keys, or an list with the given values.

If you specify `strict=True`, it will only validate dictionaries and list that have *exactly* these keys/values.

For example:

```
KeysValidator(keys=['a', 'b'])({'a': 4, 'b': 2})  # valid
KeysValidator(keys=['a', 'b'])({'a': 4})  # ValidationError: ['Some keys were missing: b']
KeysValidator(keys=['a', 'b'])({})  # ValidationError: ['Some keys were missing: b, a']
KeysValidator(keys=['a', 'b'])([])  # ValidationError: ['Some keys were missing: b, a']
KeysValidator(keys=['a', 'b'])(['a', 'b'])  # succeeds
KeysValidator(keys=['a', 'b'])(['a', 'b', 'c'])  # succeeds
KeysValidator(keys=['a', 'b'], strict=True)({'a': 4, 'b': 2, 'c': 3})  # ValidationError: ['Some unknown keys were provided: c']
KeysValidator(keys=['a', 'b'], strict=True)({'a': 4, 'b': 2})  # succeeds
KeysValidator(keys=['a', 'b'], strict=True)({'a': 4, 'c': 3})  # ValidationError: ['Some keys were missing: b']
KeysValidator(keys=['a', 'b'], strict=True)(['b', 'a'])  # succeeds
KeysValidator(keys=['a', 'b'], strict=True)(['b', 'a', 'c'])  # ValidationError: ['Some unknown keys were provided: c']
```

While this also works on *lists* or *strings*, the idea is that this is probably only used for dictionaries.